# Intersection of two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two spaces of matrices which are given below

> $$W_1 = \begin{cases} \\  \begin{pmatrix}
>  a&-a \\
>  c& d\end{pmatrix}\end{cases} \text{where a,c,d $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$}  $$ 
>   $$W_2=\begin{cases} \\  \begin{pmatrix}
>  a&-b \\
>  -a& d\end{pmatrix}\end{cases} \text{where a,b,d $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$}$$

now i have to find the $W_1 \cap W_2$

i don't know how to solve this question systematically .I know that answer is $\begin{pmatrix}
a & -a\\ 
-a & d
\end{pmatrix}$ but i got this answer by some random logic .Please provide me the proper solution of this

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to find all matrices $A=\begin{bmatrix} w & x \\ y & z \end{bmatrix}$ that are in both $W_1$ and $W_2$, in other words $A \in W_1 \cap W_2$.  So the gameplan is this:

> Given any matrix $A \in W_1$, find any restrictions needed for it to also be in $W_2$.  Similarly, given any matrix $A \in W_2$, find any restrictions needed for it to also be in $W_1$

Let's follow the gameplan:

- Given matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} w & x \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} \in W_1$, we must have $x=-w$ by the definition of $W_1$, so
  $$A=\begin{bmatrix} w & -w \\ y & z \end{bmatrix}$$
  But for $A$ to be in $W_2$, we also need that $y=-w$. So
  $$A=\begin{bmatrix} w & -w \\ -w & z \end{bmatrix}$$
  which is exactly the form me wanted.
- Similarly, the same reasoning can be used starting with $A=\begin{bmatrix} w & x \\ y & z \end{bmatrix} \in W_2$, to show that it is in $W_1$ only if the matrix has the desired form (you should try this direction yourself).

So we conclude that 
$$ W_1 \cap W_2 = \left\{ A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}:A= \begin{bmatrix} w & -w \\ -w & z \end{bmatrix} \right\} $$

Answer (score 1):

Consider a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
 r&s \\
 t&u\end{pmatrix}$ which is in both $W_1$ and  $W_2$.

You must have $s=-r$ to be in $W_1$ and $t=-r$ to be in $W_2$

The matrix therefore has the form $\begin{pmatrix}
 r& -r \\
 -r&u\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

The negative sign in front of the $b$ in $W_2$ is a red herring.

A $2\times2$ real matrix is in $W_1$ iff the top right entry is the negative of the top left entry. A $2\times2$ real matrix is in $W_2$ iff the bottom left entry is the negative of the top left entry.

Therefore a matrix is in both sets iff the top right entry is the negative of the top left entry *and* the bottom left entry is the negative of the top left entry (this is what a set intersection means: the elements in both sets).